# Application performance degradation due to several large in memory Dictionary objects in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, optimization

I am working on a winforms application where I have to load data from  Web API calls. Few million rows of data will be returned and had to be stored in a Dictionary.  The logic goes like this. User will click on an item and data would be loaded. If the user clicks on another item, another new dictionary would be created.During the course of time several such heavy weight Dictionary objects would be created.  The user might not use the old Dictionary objects after some time. Is this a case for using WeakReference?. Note that recreating any Dictionary object would take 10 to 20 secs.  If I opt to keep all the objects in memory, the application performance degrades slowly after some time.

Comment: " Is this a case for using WeakReference?" - I'd say it's a case for using a database.

Comment: Why do you need to load so much data? Is the user going to look at those million rows?

Comment: I think that you have a projectation problem

Comment: `Note that recreating any Dictionary object would take 10 to 20 sec`. Then it's not for a `WeakReference`. A `WeakReference`-ed object creation should be cheap. And anyway if  you have a need for a `WeakRefernce` it's a red flag that something is wrong with design.

Comment: Does the API force you to fetch _all_ of the data? Or would it be possible to introduce paging?

Comment: The dictionary does not copy original data but create links to original data.  A few million long integers [long key, long pointer] is not a lot of memory.

Comment: All of the data is required on the client side (no paging). It would be fed into a ML algorithm.  This is TimeSeries data and the data is retrieved based on some granularity. Like - give me data for the year 2016 & 2017 could be one query. There could be several such queries triggered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to use a more advanced technique.

Use a memory-mapped file to store the dictionaries on disk; then you don't have to worry about holding them all in memory at once as they will be swapped in and out by the OS per demand.

You will want to write a Dictionary designed specifically to operate in the memory mapped file region, and a heap to store things pointed to by the key value pairs in the dictionary.  Since you aren't deleting anything, this is actually pretty straightforward.

Otherwise you should take Fildor 4's suggestion and Just Use A Database, as it will basically do everything I just mentioned for you and wrap it up in a nice syntax.

Comment: Is there any solution which I can use as reference for this implementation?